# Get percentages of dummyvariables

Tags: r, percentage, dummy-variable

relatively new to R.

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
VAR01 <- c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No')
VAR02 <- c('No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes')
VAR03 <- c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes')

data <- data.frame(VAR01, VAR02, VAR03)
```

How do i get the percentages of Yes and No for each column? Potentially for hundred of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` would count the occurrences of each unique value and `prop.table` would return the percentage. To apply this for multiple columns you can use any of the apply command.

```
sapply(data, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))

#    VAR01     VAR02     VAR03
#No    0.5 0.6666667 0.3333333
#Yes   0.5 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `colMeans` assuming that *no* will be `1 - yes`:

```
colMeans(data=="Yes")
#    VAR01     VAR02     VAR03 
#0.5000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

Or for each:

```
x  <-  colMeans(data=="Yes")
rbind(yes = x, no = 1- x)
#    VAR01     VAR02     VAR03
#yes   0.5 0.3333333 0.6666667
#no    0.5 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

using `across`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~mean(.x == "Yes") )) %>%
  add_row(1 - .[,c(1:3)]) %>% magrittr::set_rownames(c("yes", "no"))

    VAR01     VAR02 VAR03
yes   0.5 0.3333333   0.5
no    0.5 0.6666667   0.5
```